# Debug-able Domain Specific Language

Tags: dsl

My goal is to develop a DSL for my application but I want the user to be able to put a break-point in his/her DSL **without** the user to know anything about the underlying language that the DSL runs on and he/she see is the DSL related syntax, stack, watch variables and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your target platform. For example, if you're implementing your DSL compiler on top of .NET, it is trivial to annotate your bytecode with debugging information (variable names, source code location for expressions and statements, etc.).

If you also provide a Visual Studio extension for your language, you'll be able to reuse a royalty-free MSVS Isolated Shell for both editing and debugging for your DSL code.

Nearly the same approach is possible with JVM (you can use Eclipse or Netbeans as a debugging frontend).

Native code generation is a little bit more complicated, but it is still possible to do some simple things, like generating C code stuffed with `line` pragmas.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to generate code for your DSL with built-in opportunities for breakpoints, each with built-in facilities for observing the internal state variables.  Then your debugger has know how to map locations in the DSL to the debug breakpoints, and for each breakpoint, simply call the observers. (If the observers have names, e.g., variable names, you can let the user choose which ones to call).